# What is the procedure to call sibling at your place?

Tags: visa, france, family

I am from India and living in Paris, France. I am wondering what is the process to call my brother (sibling) to stay here for a while (more than a tourist time period).

I have a Talent Passport visa. I looked at few sites, it mentioned that you have the permission to call your family and partner, but it is not very specific.

Anyone who can explain me the process or guide me to where to look up these things.

Comment: I do not think there is such a procedure. The "accompanying family" procedure (a simplified version of family reunion) allows the person you’re married to and your minor children to reside in France for the duration of your stay, without doing the family reunification procedure. https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F11166 but siblings are not included. Is your brother dependent on you?

Comment: @Traveller I would point out that the material you link to speaks of "spouse and children," which certainly suggests that siblings are generally not included.